# About Elliptic Fibration. A point of generic fibre corresponds to a section.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading Schutt and Shiva's Elliptic Surfaces.
Suppose $f:S\longrightarrow C$ is an elliptic fibration, where S is a smooth projective surface and C is a smooth projective curve.
Then the generic fibre, E = $S\times_C Spec(k(C))$, can be regarded as a curve over the function field $k(C)$.
A point $P\in E$, whose residue field is $k(C)$, is called a $k(C)$- ration point on E. 
Then $P\in E \hookrightarrow S$. The paper claims: the closure of $P\in S$ is isomorphic to the base curve C, and therefore it is a section of $f:S\rightarrow C$.

There are two points I'm confused about:

1, The paper says, P is only defined on the smooth fibre. What does this mean?

2, Why the closure of P in the surface S is a smooth curve?

Answer (score 3):

I do not understand 1). $P$ is in the generic fiber, not on other fibers. For 2), let $D$ be the closure of $P$. Then $D$ is irreducible, $f:D\to C$ is a proper map, birational, since $k(C)=k(D)$, $P$ being a $k(C)$ rational point. Since $C$ is smooth, this implies $f:D\to C$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: For example , a nodle rational curve is birational to $\mathbb{P}^1$, but not smooth. How to verify that the closure D is smooth ?

Comment: As I said, a birational morphism from an irreducible projective curve to a smooth projective curve is always an isomorphism. Follows from the fact that, this makes the map finite and locally, smooth if and only if integrally closed.